# Why and when JAXBElement is required in JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, oracle, jaxb, xsd

I am just learning JAXB (Java Architecture for XML Binding). Reading through a few sources , one doubt has come in my mind regarding `JAXBElement`. 
**Oracle docs say:**

`When XML element information can not be inferred by the derived Java representation of the XML content, a JAXBElement object is provided. This object has methods for getting and setting the object name and object value.` [Link here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnazq.html#bnazv)

**Does it mean that `JAXBElement` needs to be used when there is not a direct mapping between Schema defined datatype and Java data type?**

Further, In one of the code examples listed under. which i followed from [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/jaxb-generate-xml-xsd.html) :

```
 ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();

    UserT user = factory.createUserT();
    user.setUserName("Sanaulla");
    ItemT item = factory.createItemT();
    item.setItemName("Seagate External HDD");
    item.setPurchasedOn("August 24, 2010");
    item.setAmount(new BigDecimal("6776.5"));

    ItemListT itemList = factory.createItemListT();
    itemList.getItem().add(item);

    ExpenseT expense = factory.createExpenseT();// we get expense object here
    expense.setUser(user);
    expense.setItems(itemList);

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("generated");
    JAXBElement<ExpenseT> element = factory.createExpenseReport(expense);//why is this required
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty("jaxb.formatted.output",Boolean.TRUE);
    marshaller.marshal(element,System.out);
```

Using `ExpenseT expense = factory.createExpenseT();` we are able to get `ExpenseT` object.
 
Again in the code if we see ,we create 
`JAXBElement<ExpenseT> element = factory.createExpenseReport(expense);`
which according to [this source](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_4_1-Building-and-Marshalling-an-XML-Document.html) is a wrapper for `expense` object.
On the other hand we don't create wrappers for the objects retrieved using 
`UserT user = factory.createUserT();`

**So my questions are :**

1. What is the need of `JAXBElement` wrapper around `expense` ?
2. when to use `JAXBElement` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a few use cases where a `JAXBElement` is required:

1. An element is both `nillable="true"` and `minOccurs="0"`.  In this case what does `null` on the mapped field/property mean?  When the property is `JAXBElement` a null value means the element isn't present and a `JAXBElement` wrapping null means an XML element with `xsi:nil="true"`.
2. There are 2 global elements with the same named complex type.  Since in JAXB classes correspond to complex types a way is needed to capture which root element was encountered. For more details see this [article](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html) I wrote.
3. There is a choice structure where either `foo` or `bar` elements can occur and they are the same type.  Here a `JAXBElement` is required because simply encountering a `String` value isn't enough to indicate which element should be marshalled.
4. An element with `xsi:nil` is encountered in the document that contains attributes.  In this example the object corresponding to that element can still be unmarshalled to hold the attribute values, but JAXBElement can stil indicate that the element was null.

Comment: In the above code, even if i try to marshall `expense ` object, it generates the same XML output.So i was a bit confused, why `JAXBElement` wrapper is generated and marshalled.

Comment: @AmanArora - What does the `Expense` class look like?  Did you modify it after it was generated from the XML schema?

Comment: In the above code, when i try to marshall `expense ` object, it throws `javax.xml.bind.MarshalException exception :unable to marshal type "XSDtoXMLtoObjects.ExpenseT" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation. Sorry the last comment was wrong..

Comment: @AmanArora - I wrote a blog post about root elements that you may find useful:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html

Comment: Thank you. I will go through it now.

Answer (score 4):

JAXBElement is used to preserve the element name/namespace in use cases where enough information is not present in the object model. It's often used with substitution groups.

Without any JAXB metada the result will be wrapped in a JAXBElement.
You can eliminates the root level JAXBElement by using the @XmlRootElement annotation.

If you use xsd files from an external source and no XmlRootElement annotation is available on the generated classes, using JAXBElement during the marshalling process can really come in handy since you can unmarshal the xml to an object using the JAXBElement wrapper. You will see that specifying the class itself doesn't work in that case...

This will work:

```
JAXBElement<Object> je = (JAXBElement<Object>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(objectXML);
Object = je.getValue();
```

This will throw a JAXBException:

```
Object obj = (Object) unmarshaller.unmarshal(objectXML);
```