# When does JAXB generates @XmlElementRef and @XmlElement type of annotations?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

This question has been asked a multiple times in different ways, but I have a query from a different perspective here. So let's take below example :

```
<xs:element name="Ric" type="String" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
```

For above line in XSD the JAXB generated below code :

```
@XmlElementRef(name = "Ric", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<String> ric;
```

but for following xsd element,

```
<xs:element name="Ric" type="String" minOccurs="0"/>
```

I get,

```
 @XmlElement(name = "Ric")
    protected String ric;
```

I have read several explanations of the difference between `@XmlElement` vs `@XmlElementRef` but since I am very new to working with XSDs I could not understand what they are trying to say. All I could grasp was that for `nillable="true"` this is the case. Can someone please explain in a layman's language that why JAXB generated a parameter type for an element which has `nillable="true"` and `minOccur="0"`. I know we can do away with just one of these too, but client needs it this way.

jaxb version : 2.2.11

Answer (score 3):

JAXB is all about mapping between Java and XML, in both directions.

So for a schema of:

```
<xs:element name="Ric" type="String" minOccurs="0"/>
```

a Java like:

```
protected String ric;
```

with `ric = null` unambiguously maps to the absence of the "Ric" element (i.e. the parent element has zero "Ric" children elements).

But for a schema of:

```
<xs:element name="Ric" type="String" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
```

you wouldn't know whether a String equal to 'null' maps to zero "Ric" elements or a "Ric" element with value `xsi:nil`. So you need the extra **JAXBElement** wrapper to differentiate.

See the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396375/why-and-when-jaxbelement-is-required-in-jaxb).

Not sure my answer is any more easy to understand than that.. but maybe it helped.